# Covert byte data to Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am beginner in .net.I am trying to convert from byte to image format.I am cosing error

My code is

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byt);
                        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
                        returnImage.Save("D:\\image.jpg");
```

Occuring error in line " Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);" as "Parameter is not valid."

Comment: How is this "byte data" made? Is it created from some image or?

Comment: Well what is your byte array? Is it *actually* a valid representation of an image?

Comment: yes.It is camera data in hex

Comment: could u share some sample of ur image data via pastebin.com etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below Code

```
public static void byteArrayToImage(byte[] data)
{
     using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
     {
         Image img=new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms));
         img.Save(@"D:\image.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     }
}
```